# Is it much more resource-demanding to load 100 mysql rows than to load only 5 of them?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am doing a pagination system for about 100 items.
My question is:

Should I just load all 100 of them and then use jQuery to switch pages without reloading? Or should I use a MySQL query with "LIMIT 5" and then, each time user presses on Next Page or Previous Page, another Mysql query with LIMIT 5 is initiated?

For every item, I would have to load a thumbnail picture but I could keep it in the cache to avoid using my server bandwidth.

Which one is the best option from a server resource perspective?

Thanks in advance. Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try connecting directly to your MySql instance via the command line interface. Execute the query with 100 at at time, and then with `LIMIT 5`. Look at the msec results. This will tell you which is more efficient or less resource-demanding.

100 records at a time from MySql (depending on dataset) really is nothing. The performance hit wouldn't be noticeable for a properly written query/database schema.

That said, I vote for calling only the results you need at a time. Use the `LIMIT` clause and your jquery pagination method to make it efficient.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. But the point of using jQuery is to fake instantaneous loading. Since you suggest using jquery pagination method, are you suggesting that I could do something like "load first 15 rows. Then, when user click on "next 5", use ajax to append another five in the queue". Would that be similar to your suggestion? Thanks a lot

Comment: My response was more that you could use JQUERY/Ajax to call more results from your Sql (provided you do so in a supported method, such as calling a PHP Script). This way, you wouldn't need to reload the entire page, or transfer to another page. The Ajax/Jquery method would handle the SQL call on your pagination forward/back.

Comment: Oh ok I see what you mean, thanks a lot for your explanations. Regards

Answer (score 3):

For the server, the most efficient way would be to grab all 100 items once, send them to the client once, and have the client page through them locally. That's one possibly expensive query, but that's cheaper overall than having the client go back and forth for each additional five items.

Having said that, whether that's feasible is a different topic. You do not want to be pushing a huge amount of data to your client at once, since it'll slow down page loads and client-side processing. In fact, it's usually desirable to keep the bandwidth consumed by the client to a minimum. From that POV, making small AJAX requests with five results at a time when and only when necessary is much preferable. Unless even 100 results are so small overall that it doesn't make much of a difference.

Which one works best for you, you need to figure out.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I might go for something in between, which I described above: "Load first 15 rows. Then, when user clicks on "next 5", use ajax to append another five in the queue". Regards

Answer (score 2):

Depends significantly on your query. If it is a simple SELECT from a well-designed table (indexes set etc.) then unlee you're running on a very underpowered server, there will be no noticeable difference between requesting 100 rows and 5 rows. If it is complicated query, then you should probably limit the number of queries.

Other considerations to take into account are how long it takes to load a page, as in the actual round trip time to the server to receive the data by the client. I'm going to make the wild guess that you are in America or Europe, where internet speeds are nice a fast, not the entire world is that lucky. Limiting the number of times your site has to request data from the server is a much better metric than how much load your server has.

This is moving rapidly into UX here, but your users don't care about your server load, they don't care if this way means your load average is 0.01 instead of 0.02. They will care if you have almost instantaneous transitions between sections of your site.

Personally, I'd go with the "load all data, then page locally" method. Also remember that Ajax is your friend, if you have to, load the results page, then request the data. You can split the request into two: first page and rest of pages. There's alot of behind-the-scenes tweaks you can do to make your site seem incredibly fast, and that is something people notice.

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestion. As I described above to another user, I might find a compromise and load first 15 rows, and dynamically append  5 additional rows in the queue, when user clicks "Next 5". Regards

Answer (score 1):

I'd say, load 5 at a time and paginate. My considerations:

1. It is indeed much lighter to load 5 at a time
2. Not all of your users will navigate through all 100, so those loaded might not even be used
3. A slight load time between 5 records are something expected (i.e. most users won't complain just because they have to wait 500ms - 1s)

You can also give user options to display x number of items per page, and put `all` options as well to let users see all items in the page. Over time, you can also monitor what most of your users preference in terms of x number of items to display per page are then go with that for the default `LIMIT`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Tracking my users preference for display is an idea i'll keep in mind. Regards